# Calculate the percentage of the total of each row in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is automatically generated by PHP and manipulated by jquery, so I need to calculate the percentage of the total of each of the numerical lines, what is the best way to do this?

```html
<div id="tableResults" class="container">
  <table id="table_resultados" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th>SEX</th>
        <th class="names">FATAL</th>
        <th class="names">SERIOUS</th>
        <th class="names">OTHERS</th>
        <th class="names">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>WOMAN</td>
        <td class="VitimaFATAL">4</td>
        <td class="SERIOUS">6</td>
        <td class="OTHERS">1</td>
        <td class="Total">11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>MEN</td>
        <td class="FATAL">18</td>
        <td class="SERIOUS">28</td>
        <td class="OTHERS">23</td>
        <td class="Total">69</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>UNKNOWN</td>
        <td class="FATAL">3</td>
        <td class="SERIOUS">1679</td>
        <td class="OTHERS">3129</td>
        <td class="Total">4811</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="Totais">
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td id="FATAL">25</td>
        <td id="SERIOUS">1713</td>
        <td id="OTHERS">3153</td>
        <td id="Total">4891</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've already been able to sum all the values

```
        function colSum() {

        var ids = new Array();
        $('#table_resultados .names').each(function ()
        {   

            ids.push($(this).html().replace(/\s/g, ''));
            $('#Totais').append('<td id="' + $(this).html().replace(/\s/g, '') + '"></td>')

        });

        $.each(ids, function (index, value) {
            var sum = 0;
            $('.' + value).each(function () {
                sum += parseInt($(this).html());

            });
            $('#' + value).html(sum);


        });
```

I need to calculate the percentage of the total of all the columns in this example I need to insert a column after the FATAL, SERIOUS, OUTHERS call '% of total' and with values ex:% column of FATAL total would be 36.36 - 26.08 - 0.06 - 0.51 the% column of the total SERIOUS would be 54.54 - 40.57 - 34.89 - 35.02

Comment: Could you clean up your code example and be a little more clear please?

Comment: I've already been able to sum all the values

Comment: show us the php that makes the table, it would be best to use that rather than jquery

Comment: Not even clear what percentage comparison you want or where you want to present it

Comment: @charlietfl I need to calculate the percentage of the total of all the columns in this example I need to insert a column after the FATAL, SERIOUS, OUTHERS call '% of total' and with values ex:% column of FATAL total would be 36.36 - 26.08 - 0.06 - 0.51 the% column of the total SERIOUS would be 54.54 - 40.57 - 34.89 - 35.02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var total_per = 0;
$.each($('#table_resultados td.Total'), function() {  
  if (!isNaN($(this).text())) {
    total_per = total_per + parseInt($(this).text());
  }
});
console.log('Total: ' + total_per);

$.each($('#table_resultados tbody tr'), function () {
  var obj = $(this).find('.Total');
  if (!isNaN(obj.text())) {
     var v = parseInt(obj.text());

     $('<td></td>')
     .text( parseFloat((v / total_per) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%' )
     .appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableResults" class="container">
  <table id="table_resultados" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th>SEX</th>
        <th class="names">FATAL</th>
        <th class="names">SERIOUS</th>
        <th class="names">OTHERS</th>
        <th class="names">TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>WOMAN</td>
        <td class="VitimaFATAL">4</td>
        <td class="SERIOUS">6</td>
        <td class="OTHERS">1</td>
        <td class="Total">11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>MEN</td>
        <td class="FATAL">18</td>
        <td class="SERIOUS">28</td>
        <td class="OTHERS">23</td>
        <td class="Total">69</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>UNKNOWN</td>
        <td class="FATAL">3</td>
        <td class="SERIOUS">1679</td>
        <td class="OTHERS">3129</td>
        <td class="Total">4811</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="Totais">
        <td>TOTAL</td>
        <td class="FATAL">25</td>
        <td class="SERIOUS">1713</td>
        <td class="OTHERS">3153</td>
        <td class="Total">4891</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You'll notice here:

```
 <tr id="Totais">
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <td id="FATAL">25</td>
    <td id="SERIOUS">1713</td>
    <td id="OTHERS">3153</td>
    <td id="Total">4891</td>
  </tr>
```

You have `id` when it should be `class` on all those table cells.
When you want a percentage of something you take the number and divide it by the total and then multiply it by 100 to get the percentage.

Comment: I need the percentage of each column

Comment: You can make your solution from this. We don't usually write this much code for people here. Stackoverflow is where you learn to code not where you get code. Good luck.